# how to move an desktop icon without a mouse

Tags: desktop-environments

I,m using Ubuntu 18.04

Sometimes my screen resolution gets changed,
so few icons are not displayed anymore,
because they are "to the right" of the screen.

Still I can locate them, move to them, using arrow keys, or by the first letter of their name. Then I can start them, using "Enter".

And I can move the open window of any of them,
using "ALT" + "F7" + cursors, ending with ENTER.
But the icon remains not visible, to the right of the screen.

I want to move the icon to the left, so it is visible again,
and stays visible forever.

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: are Desktop Icons managed by DING Extension in your case?

Comment: Probably not! Don't the icons adjust to the lower resolution when you log out then back in? If that works, restarting the shell (Alt+F2, r) also will "reset" the icons to the current screen resolution.

Comment: DING ? how can I know who is managing them ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a way you can move them without a mouse.

However, You could try using the `Arrange Icons` option in the select menu when you right click on the Desktop.

This should neatly arrange all your icons to be on the left side of your desktop.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I shall try that !

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Did it work?

Comment: no, sorry - that menu item does not come up in Ubuntu 18.04

I am using GNOME :

    nila@mars:~$ systemctl status display-manager.service
    ● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager

However I see "Organize Desktop by Name" which should do something similar.
Thanks.